# htaccess preventing xml file to be read (flash based xml gallery)

Tags: .htaccess

I have a flash movie which resides in a folder named ‘gallery’ in the root directory. When the page is loaded, it is unable to load the xml file, but the movie loads fine. Both the xml file and the movie are located within the ‘gallery’ folder.

I am assuming it has something to do with the .htaccess file

While checking through firebug (it shows gallery.xml inside activities folder)
GET gallery.xml http://localhost/adv/activities/gallery.xml

MY htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^/]+/)*index\.php\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*)index\.php$   http://localhost/adv/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule activities/(.*) activity.php?actid=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

@localhost: It sounds like you might be trying to access the XML within Flash with relative paths instead of absolute ones; change the path to absolute and it should work.

Relative path, e.g.:
`gallery/gallery.xml`

Absolute path, e.g.:
`http://localhost/adv/gallery.xml`

Comment: I can't change the path in the flash file cause it is a free flash/xml gallery (dfgallery). Is there any way to code in htaccess so that gallery.xml will always be redirected in root folder.